# schedule and automate sqoop import/export tasks

Tags: shell, hadoop, automation, hive, sqoop

I have a sqoop job which requires to import data from oracle to hdfs.

The sqoop query i'm using is
`sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port/service --username sqoop --password sqoop --query "SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE orderdate = To_date('10/08/2013', 'mm/dd/yyyy') AND partitionid = '1' AND rownum < 10001 AND \$CONDITIONS" --target-dir /test1 --fields-terminated-by '\t'`

I am re-running the same query again and again with change in partitionid from 1 to 96. so I should execute the sqoop import command manually 96 times. The table 'ORDERS' contains millions of rows and each row has a partitionid from 1 to 96. I need to import 10001 rows from each partitionid into hdfs.

Is there any way to do this? How to automate the sqoop job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run script : $ ./script.sh 20 //------- for 20th entry

```
ramisetty@HadoopVMbox:~/ramu$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash

PART_ID=$1
TARGET_DIR_ID=$PART_ID
echo "PART_ID:" $PART_ID  "TARGET_DIR_ID: "$TARGET_DIR_ID
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port/service --username sqoop --password sqoop --query "SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE orderdate = To_date('10/08/2013', 'mm/dd/yyyy') AND partitionid = '$PART_ID' AND rownum < 10001 AND \$CONDITIONS" --target-dir /test/$TARGET_DIR_ID --fields-terminated-by '\t'
```

**For all 1 to 96  - single shot**

```
ramisetty@HadoopVMbox:~/ramu$ cat script_for_all.sh
#!/bin/bash

for part_id in {1..96};
do
 PART_ID=$part_id
 TARGET_DIR_ID=$PART_ID
 echo "PART_ID:" $PART_ID  "TARGET_DIR_ID: "$TARGET_DIR_ID
 sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port/service --username sqoop --password sqoop --query "SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE orderdate = To_date('10/08/2013', 'mm/dd/yyyy') AND partitionid = '$PART_ID' AND rownum < 10001 AND \$CONDITIONS" --target-dir /test/$TARGET_DIR_ID --fields-terminated-by '\t'
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `crontab` for scheduling purposes. Crontab documentation can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) or you could use `man crontab` in terminal.

Add your sqoop import command in shell script and execute this shell script using crontab.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, But how to change the partitionid column variable in shell script? I need to execute the sqoop command 96 times with change in partitionid and the --target-directory. Should i write a shell script with 96 sqoop commands and then execute it?